# What phrases can I use instead of "don't worry about it" in a semi-formal letter

Tags: phrases, expressions, letter-writing

Good morning, Stack Exchange! First time inquirer here.

I'm drafting a reply to an email from a scholarly peer, who apologized for not getting something to me sooner. I really don't mind the delay, and I want to express that in my reply without using informal phrases like "No big deal", or "don't worry about it".

What are some alternative phrases that I could use?

Comment: I don't think "don't worry about it" is all that casual, so I think it's fine.  I also tend to use "no worries", which is a bit more casual but I think it would be fine in this context, too.  You could also say something like "Don't think twice about it".

Comment: "There is no need to be concerned about your delay; I appreciate your taking the time to ..."

Comment: I think it would be best to use your own style of communication, rather than seem like an American that sounds like an Aussie or a Swiss that sounds Indian. Write whatever you’d say to your peer in person. Email can afford to be a little less formal than publications, especially if you’re being magnanimous.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. (+1) for a good question and a polite entrance.

Comment: Do not ask for help writing (or proofreading). “How should I write this?” and “is this correct?” questions are out of scope and your question may be removed. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”. If there is an unstated specific concern, such as “What does (word) mean in context?” or “How does (grammar or punctuation rule) apply in context?” ask that question instead. Also check out “[Where can I ask for free proofreading? – Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7571)”, and the *[Writers Stack Exchange](https://writers.stackexchange.com/)*.

Comment: As this is essentially about a work-related social interaction, it might also be appropriate at [workplace.se] or [interpersonal.se].